# Using OLS with missing panel data

Tags: least-squares, panel-data

I am trying estimate the following model using OLS

$$
Y_{t} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}X_{1t} + \beta_{2}X_{2t} + \epsilon_{t}
$$

where $Y_{t}$ is the difference between two observed variables,  $Y_{t} = Y_{t}^{1} - Y_{t}^{2}$. For a given $t$ my data cross-section would look like

```
Yt1      Yt2      X1t         X2t
0.018             0.970159    0.029242
0.018    2.031    0.913968    0.080950
0.079             0.837660    0.143741
0.211    1.920    0.709464    0.227941
0.510    1.843    0.525544    0.293679
0.839    1.818    0.405196    0.293547
         1.858    0.323700    0.269938
1.309    1.964    0.266588    0.240701
         2.082    0.225218    0.212752
1.639    2.198    0.194307    0.188305
         2.265    0.170551    0.167661
         2.341    0.151829    0.150437
1.875    2.396    0.136745    0.136074
         2.446    0.124357    0.124034
         2.499    0.114013    0.113857
         2.635    0.091223    0.091205
         2.831    0.068418    0.068418
2.542             0.045612    0.045612
```

The problem I am having is that for any given $t$ the overlap of the variables $Y_t^1$ and $Y_t^2$ can result in much less data to estimate the model than if I were to estimate each OLS individually. At first glance it seems like I could just estimate these individual and then difference the coefficients since if I were to have

$$
\begin{align}
Y_1 &= \beta_1X + \epsilon_1 \\
Y_2 &= \beta_2X + \epsilon_2 \\
Y &= Y_1 - Y_2 \\
&= (\beta_1 - \beta_2)X + \epsilon_1 - \epsilon_2\\
&\triangleq \beta X + \epsilon
\end{align}
$$
with
$$
\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_t)
$$

then I would have OLS estimators

$$
\begin{align}
\hat{\beta_1} &= (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY_1 \\
\hat{\beta_2} &= (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY_2 \\
\hat{\beta} &= (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY\\
&= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T(Y_1 - Y_2)\\
&= (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY_1 - (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY_2\\
&= \hat{\beta_1} - \hat{\beta_2}
\end{align}
$$

I was just wondering what the possible pitfalls of this solution are, i.e. what happens if you relax the assumptions on your error terms?

### P.S

To give more context of the specific problem, this relates to estimating the cross section of bond yields using a Nelson Siegel model.

### Edit

In response to the comments, I have changed the title to missing data instead of censored since this was a misuse of the word on my part. The data is provided by a third party data provider and corresponds to interest rates at different maturities. I believe that they combine an aggregation of quotes from different sources and if there are an insufficient number of sources for a given day they omit that data point. For example here is a sample of $Y_t^1$

```
Dates   3M      6M      2Y      3Y      5Y      10Y     30Y
t1      1.2610  1.6146  2.5122  2.8992  3.6319  4.4565  5.2065
t2      1.2611  1.6045  2.5133  2.8999  3.6457  4.4704  5.2226
t3      1.2303  1.5629  2.5380  2.9230          4.4743  5.2237
t4      1.2609  1.6041  2.5383  2.9232  3.6269  4.4744  5.2183
t5      1.2814  1.6042  2.5224  2.9005  3.5995  4.4550  5.2054
```

Comment: Are some values actually censored or are they just *missing*? In either case, what is the reason for this?

Comment: @whuber, updated the question in response to your comments, thanks